# Find the function by offset in the DLL (and PDB)

Tags: function, visual-c++, dll, offset, pdb

An error occurred in the self-written DLL:

```
SE EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at address 0x54E258BB inside C:\Program Files (x86)\...\...\...\lib.dll loaded at base address 0x54D80000. Invalid operation: read at address 0x0.
```

There is the DLL and the PDB file for it (and its code).

Can I watch which function is being called or which variable is being accessed, using offset?

I have calculated the offset `Offset = 0x54E258BB - 0x54D80000 = 0xA58BB`

Maybe there is a special software ... Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you calculate that offset? Is there a reason you're not using GetProcAddress?

Comment: In my error "SE EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at address 0x54E258BB", library is loaded at base address 0x54D80000. I took this data from the message.

An error occurred in an unexportable function. I have seen all export functions, there is no one with this address.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you were trying to run code at a particular offset. You have a crash due to what looks like a null pointer. Running the code in a debugger would be my first approach but if you can't do that for whatever reason you could try generating a map file when you compile and see if you can find the offset that way. It is under linker/debugging in project properties. Another option could be too take a good look at your code and figure out where you might access a null pointer. Hard to say not knowing anything about it.

Comment: Thank you, it works. It doesn't contain exactly this address, but it's very useful, I will try to review the nearest functions.